# Can I create a silent installer with Chocolatey by just using the setup.exe of a program and shimgen?

Tags: powershell, command-prompt, chocolatey

When attempting to create a silent installer for a program, can I just use that program's `setup.exe` in the tools folder and just generate a shim for it? If so, where  does it then get installed to? 
For example, I deleted all items in the tools folder and put in the `setup.exe` for `ARM RVDS 4.1`. When I did `choco pack` it generated a shim but now I don't know what to do with it, or if I did it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to set up a shim for the installer - you want to invoke the installer from `chocolateyInstall.ps1` to install the program. A sample of how you would do this in `chocolateyInstall.ps1` for a setup exe would be:

```
$packageInstallArgs = @{
  PackageName = 'package-name'
  FileType = 'exe'
  SilentArgs = '/q /someOtherArguments' # This line is going to be installer specific, and is just a sample here
  File = 'C:\Path\to\installer' # can be a relative path too
  ValidExitCodes = 0, 1638 # array of acceptable return codes for the installer
}

Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage @packageInstallArgs
```

---

> If your `setup.exe` is embedded inside the package, you can reference the current package folder directory with the following environment variable: `$env:chocolateyPackageFolder`. This variable only exists in the context of a Chocolatey package install. [See here](https://chocolatey.org/docs/HelpersReference#environment-variables) for more information on Chocolatey environment variables.

Some details about the code above:

- PackageName: This is the name (id) of the package
- FileType: Is this an 'exe' or an 'msi'?
- SilentArgs: Any arguments required to perform a silent installation of the program
- File: Relative or absolute path to the installer file
- ValidExitCodes: Any exit codes that should be treated as a successful install. The ones I used in my sample mean success (`0`) and reboot required (`1638`). See [this page](http://docs.netecm.ch/launcher/troubleshooting/msi-exit-codes.html) for more information about standard installer exit codes. Search for the error codes that start with `ERROR_SUCCESS` for the success codes you may need to support.

---

You would optionally generate shims for programs not automatically placed on the PATH for convenience, in the case a shim is not automatically generated.

Where a program gets installed depends on the default location of the installer, and whether the installer allows you to override it.

---

Note that while automatically generated shims will be removed on uninstall automatically, shims created with [`Install-BinFile`](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-bin-file) need to be manually removed on package uninstall using [`Uninstall-BinFile`](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-uninstall-bin-file) from `chocolateyUninstall.ps1`.

---

Here is some more information about shims:

- https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-shim
- https://chocolatey.org/courses/creating-chocolatey-packages/shims

Comment: So, use the `setup.exe` in the tools folder, but also the `chocolateyInstall.ps1`? In this case, would you recommend using `Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage`, or, should I not use shims at all for what I am wanting to do and just use `chocolateyInstall.ps1`?

Comment: You want to use `Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage` in your case as the executable is inside the package.

Comment: @DeZLearnsPCs I updated my answer with some examples. For a company-internal package, you can just place your installer in the tools folder, and reference it from `chocolateyInstall.ps1`.

Comment: Do I reference it by making the File: `$env:chocolateyPackageFolder`? I am trying to understand what to put as the location when the installer is in the tools folder.

Comment: So you can reference that within a path string, like so. Assuming your `setup.exe` is in the tools folder of the package directory, `"${env:chocolateyPackageFolder}\tools\setup.exe"` would be the path to the installer file.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the executable in the tools folder then Chocolatey will create a shim for it when the package is installed. The shim allows the executable to be available on the path.

What you want to do is run the installer when the package is installed and you do that using the `chocolateyInstall.ps1` file. If you run `choco new <packagename>` you will get a sample `chocolateyInstall.ps1` file you can use as a template.